# Arch linux booting into rescue shell by default

Tags: shell, arch-linux, boot, rescue

I just installed Arch in my PC alongside windows 7 but for some reason it boots directly into the rescue shell, [this is how it looks](https://www.dropbox.com/s/pofdtll4mv0htpm/2012-12-30%2001.38.37.jpg)

It doesn't show any errors though, and if I press Ctrl+D it just shows me my display manager like normal, how can I make it so it boots directly into the display manager? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try rerun `mkinitcpio -p linux`.

Comment: Thanks I just tried it but no luck, maybe I enabled it in the boot options by mistake? I'm not sure what can I post to help debugging it

Comment: Please check this: https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Mkinitcpio#Using_LVM - and of course the full article :) I think it will help you :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it to work I just had to change this:

`root=/dev/mapper/vgroup-arch--root cryptdevice=/dev/sda6:vgroup ro rootfstype=ext4 systemd.unit=graphic.target`

To this:

`root=/dev/mapper/vgroup-arch--root cryptdevice=/dev/sda6:vgroup ro rootfstype=ext4`

In my bootloader options.